# root takes up entire internal hard drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, root

I have a 500 GB internal hard drive and I cannot paste anything to it. The entire hard drive is labeled as root. Although I can use the space through `sudo nautilus`, this doesn't let me play any music or play videos because the applications don't have root access. I tried using GParted to partition the drive, but even their the min size is equal to 467 GB. How do I fix this?
I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday and I don't know anything about Ubuntu.

Comment: Where do you have your music/videos stored?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's supposed to be. As a normal user you are only interested and have access to your home folder, which is under `/home`

Open a terminal and type `ls -l /home` (that's a lowercase L, not a numerical one) and you'll see that there is a directory named after your username and its ownership is set to you. This is where you put your work.

Comment: I can't even access /home. Even home is under root.

Comment: Yes, /home belongs to root. What is the output of `ls -l /home` ?